# Was Stephen correct in his historical summation of Jewish history in the Book of Acts, Chapter 7?

Tags: bible, history, old-testament, jews, stephen

Concerning the Book of Acts, Chapter 7, I would like to know if all Christians should accept that everything that Stephen had said about Jewish history in his speech before the Sanhedrin, particularly about how the past generations of Jews had dealt with God's prophets, was correct or are there any discrepancies in what he had said.

Was Stephen correct in his historical summation of Jewish history in the Book of Acts, Chapter 7?

Comment: Is there something in particular you think he was wrong about?

Comment: @curiousdannii, no, I don't think he was wrong about anything, but I am not a Biblical scholar.

Comment: he was clearly wrong to insinuate that the ancestors of his audience persecuted all of the prophets. He also made some minor errors of fact. But most importantly, he never spoke of God's love and forgiveness for his people.

Comment: The supposed 'discrepancies' are all answered at [SE-BH](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4701/locations-of-the-graves-of-the-patriarchs/4713#4713). God's attitude to Israel and Judah is seen in the Assyrian and Babylonian captivity. God's attitude to the further rejection of Messiah ('the wrath is come upon them to the uttermost') is evident historically in 70 AD as prophesied by Jesus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What astonishes me with critics of Stephen's address to Jewish religious leaders (as recorded in Acts chapter 7) is apparent failure to consider that he was speaking for his life, to an audience so hostile to him, that being stoned to death could be only minutes away. ***He wasn't out to give a historical lecture to students wanting to learn all the details***. He had just been accused of blasphemy by false witnesses, and was charged with defending himself (Acts 6:11-15). Yet he was more concerned that he testify to Christ as the Messiah, than to offer any self-defence.

Once his speech is read with that understanding, it all becomes clear why he said what he said. He knew the High Priest, whom he was addressing, represented guardianship of the Law of Moses, the Prophets' writings, and the Wisdom literature of their forebears. That all combined to show Israel as God's chosen nation, and to point them to a coming Messiah. As custodians and interpreters of such a weighty spiritual inheritance, members of the Sanhedrin were respected and obeyed by the God-fearing Jewish populace. Nobody challenged their wisdom without incurring their wrath.

Then along came Jesus - the Messiah. But his disciples didn't fully grasp that until after witnessing him resurrected from the dead. Then their world-view was revolutionised as was their grasp of the Hebrew scriptures. Hints therein of God pouring his Holy Spirit upon Gentiles as well as Jews were now being realised as fact. The Kingdom of God wasn't a political rule with Jerusalem as the power base; it was out of this world but dramatically transforming everything worldly it touched. Stephen now understood this. Some of the Sanhedrin disputed with Stephen but ***"they were not able to resist the wisdom and the Spirit by which he spoke"*** (Acts 6:10). His accusers claimed Stephen had said Jesus would destroy the temple and change the customs of Moses. Now, in fact, Jesus *had* said things that would give rise to such a view if his hearers applied their own wisdom. Anyone considering Jesus to just be another prophet or miracle-worker could never begin to see how he was alluding to his resurrection; how he was, indeed "greater than the temple" because people would now meet with God through him (John 1:51).

Stephen's speech showed that there was no case to answer. It was his accusers who demeaned the law, over-rated the temple, and failed to recognise God's Anointed One. Stephen was never going to get a full hearing but wisely ***built up his case from national history first before concluding his accusers had resisted the Holy Spirit - the very thing that had caused their forebears to persecute the prophets of old***, sent to warn them that God desired mercy (which was not a law) above sacrifice. They had kept on with their idolatry despite the prophet's clear warnings, thus further resisting the Holy Spirit as well as abusing the prophets.

More subtly, he peppered his speech with hints about their forebears' jealousy and resentment of God's chosen ones, Joseph and Moses. The Israelites were given over to idolatry by God because of their desire for the things of Egypt - a veiled reference to the pagan bent of those owning the Tablets of God. Mere possession of the Law proved nothing. His accusers must have been smartnng, but could say nothing against quotations from the prophet Amos (re. pride). Worse, they had not learned from their national history but had exceeded its worst excesses by killing the prophet greater than Moses - the Messiah. What hypocrisy to accuse Stephen of disregarding Moses and the Law when they had done that! Then, his accusers did what guilty people generally do when determined to silence truth - they stoned the messenger.

Stephen's fearless declaration of the truth cost him his life. Luke, writing the account, gave eyewitness evidence to show clearly who Jesus was, what Christians believed, and to assure readers that Gentiles were absolutely included in the Kingdom of God. Saul, who heard Stephen's speech and witnessed his martyrdom, became the Apostle to the Gentiles.

But at the time, Saul and the Sanhedrin's world-view placed Jerusalem and its temple as central to God's Kingdom, with themselves as key players. Such self-centred wisdom allowed for no carpenter from Nazareth to snatch away their position, to cast it open to despised Gentiles! Their philosophy was actually self-idolising - pagan.

Stephen's world-view was divinely and perfectly balanced. He was full of faith, power and wisdom because Christ, the Wisdom of God, permeated his entire philosophy. No wonder his face shone like an angel's! Christ's Spirit had spoken words of scripture to him, renewing his mind, correcting his faulty human wisdom. He now saw the Big Picture in God's dealings with Israel so could see his own day, and days of yore, in light of Christ's ascension. No wonder he saw heaven opened and Jesus standing at God's right hand!

Stephen's speech was exquisitely Christ-centred. Only when that is realised will his references to prophets be seen as wisdom from above, given to him. But if all the attention is on historic details about the prophets, then the point about Christ will be missed and, like the initial hearers, hands will effectively cover ears, with a rush to silence Stephen with further accusations. **Stephen was more correct than most people will ever realise.**

Comment: Anne, I think that is an excellent analysis of Stephen's speech.

Comment: As one of those critics I think Stephen should be judged by his fruits. Before he spoke, priests were joining the church in large numbers. Acts 6:7 After he spoke, a persecution led by priests broke out against the church. (Acts 8) If he had been truly inspired in his speech I think he would have shown love to his enemies and urged them to repent. He did neither. I have to conclude that his speech - while truthful in important ways - did not bring the Gospel message to his audience. In the end, he echoed Jesus in asking God not to hold their sin against him. In that he was truly a saint.

Answer (score 1):

Was it fair to characterize the ancestors of the Jews to whom Stephen spoke as being frequent persecutors of God's prophets? Some who claim that Stephen's charge is accurate say that he spoke in hyperbole, not meaning all the prophets, just a fair number of them. Additionally, we have to argue from silence. We know nothing about the lives of many of the prophets so do not know how they were treated or died. Some extra-biblical sources add to the list of persecuted prophets. However, we have one unimpeachable and knowledgeable person who can back up Stephen: the Lord Jesus.

> 29 “Woe to you, scribes and Pharisees, hypocrites! For you build the
> tombs of the prophets and decorate the monuments of the righteous, 30
> saying, ‘If we had lived in the days of our fathers, we would not have
> taken part with them in shedding the blood of the prophets.’ 31 **Thus
> you witness against yourselves that you are sons of those who murdered
> the prophets.** 32 Fill up, then, the measure of your fathers. 33 You
> serpents, you brood of vipers, how are you to escape being sentenced
> to hell? 34 Therefore I send you prophets and wise men and scribes,
> some of whom you will kill and crucify, and some you will flog in your
> synagogues and persecute from town to town, 35 so that on you may come
> all the righteous blood shed on earth, from the blood of righteous
> Abel to the blood of Zechariah the son of Barachiah, whom you murdered
> between the sanctuary and the altar. 36 Truly, I say to you, all these
> things will come upon this generation. (Matthew 23:29-36)

As for the timeline of Abraham's calling and travels, a satisfactory explanation that resolves apparent contradictions is given at [Can you explain the apparent contradictions in Stephen's speech in Acts 7 with Genesis?](https://evidenceforchristianity.org/can-you-explain-the-apparent-contradictions-in-stephens-speech-in-acts-7-with-genesis/).

One possible interpretation is that Abraham's calling came in two parts:

1. Leave your country: Result, move to Haran.
2. Leave your people: Result, move away from Haran and his father Terah.

The article goes into the details.

Comment: @Dan Fefferman. I want to comment on a couple of things you stated. 1. Stephen never mentioned Gods love or His mercy etc. So what! In logic your arguing from silence any time you point to specific data that is not present or said. For example, I cannot show you a verse in the Book of Acts that states Jesus Christ is God either. Shall we then use your damaged logic and say that Jesus is not God? Lastly, you stated, "Stephen did not even mention the name of Jesus in his speech." Acts 7:59, "And they went on stoning Stephen as he called upon the Lord and said, LORD JESUS receive my spirit!

Comment: My answer to "so what" is that the OP asked if Stephen's speech was an accurate summation of Jewish history. Not mentioning God's love for and forgiveness of His people is not a minor omission.  It misses a central theme... in fact THE central theme IMO.

Answer (score -1):

Scholars have noticed some minor discrepancies in Stephen's account. Others see an important problem of emphasis on his part, which focuses only on Israel's rebellion and God's rejection of her, while ignoring the Bible's repeated expressions of God's everlasting love and mercy toward his chosen people. He was clearly mistaken in his insinuation that his hearers' ancestors persecuted virtually all of the prophets. Finally, there is a question as to whether Stephen, a deacon who was tasked to care for the Hellenistic Jews, spoke appropriately in his preaching to the high priest and the Sanhedrin.

### Discrepancies

- In Acts 7:2-8 - Stephen says God appeared to Abraham in Mesopotamia, but Gn 12:1 says this took place in Haran.
- Acts 7:16 Stephen claims that Jacob was buried in Shechem, whereas Gn 50:13 says he was buried at Hebron.
- The same verse reports that the tomb was purchased by Abraham, but in Gn 33:19 and Jos 24:32 the purchase is attributed to Jacob himself. (Source: footnote in the NABRE translation of Acts 7)

### Stephen's Emphasis

Throughout his speech, Stephen never mentions God's love, his mercy or his forgiveness of Israel. He summarizes Israel's actions as being only rebellious:

> 51 “You stiff-necked people, uncircumcised in heart and ears, you
> always oppose the holy Spirit; you are just like your ancestors. 52
> Which of the prophets did your ancestors not persecute?

In fact the Bible records only few instances the prophets being persecuted, and in most of those case the persecution was carried out by evil kings, not the ancestors of Stephen's audience. (Source: Gary Gilbert in *The Jewish Annotated New Testament*.)

Shockingly, Stephen did not even, Stephen did not even mention the name of Jesus in his speech. Nor did he invite his hearers to repent and receive forgiveness.

### The Limit of Stephen's Mission

Finally, in Acts 6 we learn that Stephen was assigned to supervise the group we now call "deacons." His mission was to care for the needy among the Hellenistic Jewish Christians in Jerusalem, in order that the apostles could concentrate on evangelizing.

> The Twelve called together the community of the disciples and said,
> “It is not right for us to neglect the word of God to serve at
> table. 3 Brothers, select from among you seven reputable men,
> filled with the Spirit and wisdom, whom we shall appoint to this task,
> 4 whereas we shall devote ourselves to prayer and to the ministry of
> the word.”...7 The word of God continued to
> spread, and the number of the disciples in Jerusalem increased
> greatly; even a large group of priests were becoming obedient to the
> faith.

All seemed to be going well, and even Temple priests were joining in large numbers. Soon, however, Stephen stirred up trouble among the Jews from outside Judea in the "Synagogue of Freedmen, Cyrenians, and Alexandrians, and people from Cilicia and Asia" (6:9). He was the arrested and faced the high priest in a spirit of dissent and condemnation. His speech and the martyrdom that followed marked a turning point in the church's relations with the priesthood and the Sanhedrin, precipitating the persecution of the church detailed in Acts 8.

### Conclusion

Although the text states that Stephen was "filled with grace and power, working great wonders and signs among the people," (6:8) one may suspect that - in his speech before the high priest and the Sanhedrin - he was out of his depth. Far from being "100% correct in his historical summation of Jewish history" he made several errors of fact. It is definitely not true that the Jews persecuted all of the prophets.  But these mistakes pale in comparison to Stephen's omission God's love and mercy toward his people, a central theme of Providential history. He also missed a golden opportunity to declare the gospel to his hearers, who included the key leaders of Judaism.

---

Note on the prophets: Stephen may have been referring to a contemporary writing called [the Lives of the Prophets](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Lives_of_the_Prophets). It provides details not found in the scriptures about how many of the prophets died. It does not go as far as Stephen does in his denunciation of his hearers' ancestors, but it does say that several of the prophets died violent deaths.

Comment: It is quite clear that God spoke twice to Abraham, the second time after the death of Terah in Haran, the first being previous to that. All of your supposed 'discrepancies' are answered at SE-BH -------> [Answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4701/locations-of-the-graves-of-the-patriarchs/4713#4713). God's attitude to the repeated rebellion of particularly Israel but also Judah are apparent in the Assyrian captivity and the Babylonian captivity. And again in 70 AD.

Comment: These discrepancies have been noted by eminent scholars so they are not only mine but I do admit that biblical inerrantantist scholars have provided explanations. God did punish the Israelites, but he never left them without hope in his mercy and forgiveness. Stephen only condemns.

Comment: Forgiveness is found in belief not repentance.

Comment: @DanFefferman Again, I have to say "so what" that Stephen only condemns. The book of Acts is a "narrative" as opposed to being "didactic," which means: "We need to remember that stories are stories; they're narrative in nature, not didactic (i.e. intending to directly instruct). This is especially necessary when reading the book of Acts because it portrays the early church rather than the Old Testament people of God." Stephen was in the "throes" of death when he read the Jews the "riot" act showing how hypocritical the charges against him were. He was not there to say, "Jesus loves you."

Comment: Maybe I should have answered more narrowly, but to answer the OP I do not believe Christians should take Stephen's speech as a correct summation of Jewish history. I was raised in a Jewish family, and Stephen's speech has always struck me as missing the mark. Whether it was Luke's intent to have Stephen teach us authoritatively or not, many Christians do look at Jewish history through his eyes, and that is unfortunate -- something like seeing English history through the eyes of Joan of Arc.